# How to handle a phishing site?

Tags: phishing

I launched my company website a month ago, now when I google using website name a phishing site that has exactly copied my site appears in the first page. It also has a better rank than my website which was initially at first page, but now it isn’t. How to handle this situation and prevent this in the future since a part of my service includes developing websites for my clients.

Comment: Consider checking the `whois` of the website and contact the registrar about the abuse. A valid registrar should investigate your claims and hopefully remove that domain or hand it over to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can start by reporting the website to multiple parties in order for it to be blacklisted. An example is [Google Safe Browsing](https://safebrowsing.google.com/) which ships with Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox, you can start by filling out the [form](https://safebrowsing.google.com/safebrowsing/report_phish/?hl=en).

[Decent Security](https://decentsecurity.com/#/malware-web-and-phishing-investigation/) also has a dedicated guide for steps to take when reporting phishing sites.